# I am reading in text from a file in C# using a delimiter of '|', creating class objects from the text and then pushing these objects onto a List

Tags: c#, list, text, streamreader

The issue is, every entry in my list becomes a copy of the entry that was just added.

So basically, if I end up with 10 objects in my list (10 lines in the text file), all 10 objects in the list will become a copy of the 10th object. This is true at any point during the loop, if I stop on the 6th iteration, all 5 previous entries will now be a copy of the 6th line I am adding.. this is my loop:

```
StreamReader lolz = new StreamReader("test.txt");

while (!lolz.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = lolz.ReadLine();
    string[] lines = line.Split('|');
    {
        tasksList.Add(new TaskList(lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3], lines[4], lines[5], lines[6]));
    }
}
```

Makes 0 sense to me.

Comment: Is TaskList possibly a static object or are the member variables static?

Comment: List<TaskList> tasksList = new List<TaskList>();

TaskList is my class

Comment: why do you have the curly braces around the tasksList.Add call?

Comment: CharlesC got the right answer, my class variables were all static. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the braces, instead of the

```
string[] lines = line.Split('|');
{
    tasksList.Add(new TaskList(lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3], lines[4], lines[5], lines[6]));
}
```

just

```
string line = lolz.ReadLine();
string[] lines = line.Split('|');
tasksList.Add(new TaskList(lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3], lines[4], lines[5], lines[6]));
```

It seems you are getting the last object by reference, you shoudl check if you aren't using an static class or static members, maybe you should post the entire code to properly answer your question...

It should be used something like this:

```
using(StreamReader lolz = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
{
    string line;
    string[] lines;
    while ((line = lolz .ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lines = line.Split('|');
        tasksList.Add(new TaskList(lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3], lines[4], lines[5], lines[6]));
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Thanks for posting, but it was static class variables that was my issue

Comment: if any of these answers resolve your question, post your answer and check it as the correct answer

Comment: I'm presently unable to answer my own question after such a short amount of time.